# Procedure or function "registerStudent" expects parameter "@EmailUsername", which was not supplied.'

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

Other people have ran into this similar issue, however I am pretty positive that I'm passing in parameters as necessary, and that I have command type set to stored procedure. I also do a console log in JavaScript file to output whatever is in the textboxes, and yet there is still some error with the API it seems. I need another set of eyes to hopefully find something that I'm missing. Thanks for any help in advance.

**JavaScript Code**

```
function registerStudent()
{

    
    var studentID = document.getElementById('id').value;
    var studentEmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var studentEmailPassword = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var studentFirstName = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var studentLastName = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    
    console.log(studentID + "," + studentEmail + "," + studentEmailPassword + "," + studentFirstName + "," + studentLastName);
    

    if ((studentID=='') || (studentEmail=='') || (studentEmailPassword=='') || (studentFirstName=='') || (studentLastName==''))
    {
        alert("Please fill in all fields to register");
        return false;
    }
    
    var postObj = {
        ID: studentID,
        EmailUsername: studentEmail,
        EmailPassword: studentEmailPassword,
        FirstName: studentFirstName,
        LastName: studentLastName
    };


    var apiRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    apiRequest.open('POST', 'https://localhost:44379/api/JSON/registerStudent', true);
    apiRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
    apiRequest.onreadystatechange = function() 
    { 
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) 
        {

            if (apiRequest.response=="-1")
            {
                alert("User already exists");
                return false;
            }
            
            if (apiRequest.response=="1") 
            {
                alert("User registered");
                return false;
            }
                    
        }
    }
    
    apiRequest.send(JSON.stringify(postObj));
    
    return false;
}
```

**C# ASP.NET RESTFUL WEB API CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace AiAngelsAPI.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class JSONController : ApiController
    {
        /********************
         * Register Student
         ********************/
        
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public object registerStudent(Models.RegisterStudent student)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            string sqlStoredProcedureName = "registerStudent";
            var json = ExecuteRegisterStudent(sqlStoredProcedureName, student.id, student.email, student.password, student.firstname, student.lastname);

            response.Content = new StringContent(json);
            return response;
        }
        private static string ExecuteRegisterStudent(string storedProcedureNameSqlQuery, string studentID, string emailUsername, string emailPassword, string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            string json = "";
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseConnection"].ToString();

            using (SqlConnection databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                databaseConnection.Open();

                // 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureNameSqlQuery, databaseConnection);

                // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", studentID));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailUsername", emailUsername));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailPassword", emailPassword));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", firstname));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Lastname", lastname));


                // execute the command
                using (SqlDataReader returnData = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // iterate through results, printing each to console
                    while (returnData.Read())
                    {
                        json = (string)returnData[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

**SQL Stored Procedure Code**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[registerStudent] 

-- variables that will be passed into stored procedure (input)
                @ID varchar(16),
                @EmailUsername varchar(100),
                @EmailPassword varchar(50),
                @FirstName varchar(100),
                @LastName varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

-- if structure to check if student already exists/has registered
    if 1 = (select count(*) 
            from [dbo].[Student]
            where [studentEmailUsername] = @EmailUsername)
    begin
        select -1; -- student already exists, returns -1 as indicator
        return;
    end

-- inserts input into table/registers student by adding to database
    insert into [dbo].[Student] (studentID,studentEmailUsername,studentEmailPassword,studentFirstName,studentLastName)
    values (@ID,@EmailUsername,@EmailPassword,@FirstName,@LastName)
 
    select 1; -- student is added to database, returns 1 as indicator
    return;

END
```

**Error in API**

[Click here to see error that comes up in API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGLIk.jpg)

Comment: I think its telling you that there is no value present for EmailUsername, have you set a breakpoint and verified there is a value there?

Comment: In my javascript file I did a console log to make sure a value is being sent into the post object, I dont really know where or what the error is because Im pretty positive that I have all the correct input values and parameters

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in your C# code on the command.Parameters for email user name? My guess is that it's not what you think it is....can you please update your question and share your Models.RegisterStudent model as well?